# tag box bind with angular js but not all value capture in id in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller("xyzController", ["$scope", "$location", "$window", "$http", function ($scope, $location, $window, $http) {

    $scope.addTagList = [];
    $scope.addTag = function () {  
        var branchid = $("#element").val();
        var list = branchid.split("|");
        var empid = list[0].trim();
        var employee_name = list[1].trim();

        $scope.addTagList.push({
            empid: empid,
            employee_name: employee_name,
        });
    }

    $scope.RemoveAnswer = function (index) {
         $scope.addTagList.splice(index, 1);
    }
}]);
```

Today I am facing a problem like multiple tag box bind with angular js ng-repeat then tags show multiple in html but all tags wanted to hold in array in javascript variable but only get only first value get. And above code correctly running add and remove tags.

```
<input type="button"  value="Add" class="form-control btn-sm btn-danger"   ng-click="addTag()"/>

<div id="tags"   style="margin: 6px;font-size:10px;" ng-repeat="item in addTagList" class="label label-danger"><span  >{{item.empid}} | {{item.employee_name}} </span>  | <a><span ng-click="RemoveAnswer($index)">X</span></a>  </div> </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ui-select for such select and tagging feature.

repo: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

demo: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-tagging.html
[image]